# Apache tomcat installation causes error

Tags: java, tomcat, server

I installed jdk1.8 and now trying to install apache tomcat. When I run

```
C:\Program Files\apache\apache-tomcat-8.0.30\bin>startup
```

it start running like

```
C:\Program Files\apache\apache-tomcat-8.0.30\bin>startup
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Program Files\apache\apache-tomcat-8.0.30"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\apache\apache-tomcat-8.0.30"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Program Files\apache\apache-tomcat-8.0.30\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_73"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\apache\apache-tomcat-8.0.30\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\apache\apache-tomcat-8.0.30\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
```

after that I tried to check apache tomcat in browser like `localhost:8080`
and showing following error

```
HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp

type Exception report

message java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:176)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:375)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:131)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:62)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:171)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:375)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.30 logs.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.30
```

Please tell me how resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your `JAVA_HOME` is pointing to the correct JDK.